Tangent space to locus of varieties containing a given subvariety (Hilbert schemes)
Suppose that I have a variety $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^r$ of a given type. Then I know that the tangent space to the irreducible component $\mathcal{H}_X$ of the Hilbert scheme containing $[X]$ can be expressed as $H^0(X, \mathcal{N}_{X/\mathbb{P}^r})$.
Now suppose $X$ contains a subvariety $Y$, and I am interested in the tangent space of the locus of varieties of type $X$ which contain $Y$. I would like to say that the tangent space is isomorphic to $H^0(X, \mathcal{N}_{X/\mathbb{P}^r} \otimes \mathcal{I}_Y)$.
My questions are:

How do you phrase this locus correctly, so that the tangent space is $H^0(X, \mathcal{N}_{X/\mathbb{P}^r} \otimes \mathcal{I}_Y)$? Do you take all the closed points $[X'] \in \mathcal{H}_X$ such that $Y \subset X$, then take its closure?
Can you show or point me to a reference which shows that the tangent space is isomorphic to $H^0(X, \mathcal{N}_{X/\mathbb{P}^r} \otimes \mathcal{I}_Y)$?


Maybe it makes sense to consider the component nested Hilbert scheme parameterizing pairs $Y' \subset X'$ containing the pair $Y \subset X$ and the natural projection to $\mathcal{H}_Y$. Then the question is about the tangent space to the fiber of this map, right? Since the tangent space to the nested Hilbert scheme is well understood, this should be easy.

@Sasha I like your approach, but after some digging, I have another question. On page 230, end of section 4.5.1, in "Deformation of algebraic schemes" by Sernesi, there is a remark that one can define a Hilbert functor parameterizing closed subschemes $Y$ such that $X \subset Y \subset \mathbb{P}^r$. He claims it is representable by a projective scheme. My question is: is it clear that this approach via representability of a Hilbert functor will give the same space as the fiber approach you have described?

You can compare the definitions of the functors (the nested Hilbert scheme functor vs the functor in the book of Sernesi); if they are the same, then the representing schemes are the same.

I compared the functor of the scheme-theoretic fiber and that particular nested Hilbert functor and they match. Thanks so much!
